# Intermittent Authentication Issue connecting to bitbucket repo

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, multibranch-pipeline

Currently we are facing an issue after Bitbucket stopped supporting account passwords to connect to their repos (last March).
Before March we were using account password and we never have faced any authentication issue.
We have updated the existing Credential in Jenkins Credential store with app password to connect to our bitbucket.
Since that time we are facing the intermittent issue where we receive the below error:

> ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --no-tags --progress – https://bitbucket.org/organization-x/promotion-service.git +refs/heads/squad5-dev:refs/remotes/origin/squad5-dev" returned status code 128:
> stdout:
> stderr: remote: Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for Git authentication.

Currently we are resolving the issue by running the pipeline again (without doing any change) and it runs fine the second or third time we trigger it.

I would really appreciate your support on this matter, as we are currently facing this issue during our deployment in production environment.

more details can be found in the this link:
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-68829

**Environment details:**

- Jenkins version: 2.303.3
- git version: 2.17.1
- java.runtime.version: 1.8.0_312
- bitbucket version: 214.v2fd4234d0554
- os.arch amd64
- os.name Linux
- os.version 5.4.0-1065-aws

**Pipeline code**

```
def call(Map pipelineArgs){
  
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    booleanParam(name: 'DeployOnPreprod', defaultValue: false, description: 'Whether to deploy the build in preprod environment?')  
  }  
  options {
    timeout(time: 2, unit: 'HOURS') 
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr:'10', daysToKeepStr: '28', artifactNumToKeepStr: '5', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '14'))
  }
  environment {
    ORG = utility.getOrgName()
    APP_NAME = utility.getAppName()
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_ORG = utility.getECRName()
    ENV_NAME = utility.getEnvironment("$BRANCH_NAME")
    BUILD_OPTS = 'clean build jacocoTestReport'
    GIT_CRED_ID = 'BitBucketAdmin'
    REPO_URL = utility.getRepoURL()
    PARENT_ENV_NAME = utility.getEnvConfigValue('PARENT_ENV_NAME')
    AWS_ACCOUNT = utility.getEnvConfigValue('AWS_ACCOUNT')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Git Pull') {
      when { anyOf { branch 'dev'; branch 'release'; branch '*squad*'} }
      environment {
        //PREVIEW_VERSION = "$BRANCH_NAME-$BUILD_NUMBER".replaceAll('\\/','_')
        PREVIEW_VERSION = "$BRANCH_NAME-$BUILD_NUMBER"
        PREVIEW_NAMESPACE = "$APP_NAME-$BRANCH_NAME".toLowerCase()
        HELM_RELEASE = "$PREVIEW_NAMESPACE".toLowerCase()
        DOCKER_REGISTRY = "${env.DOCKER_REGISTRY_ORG}"
        DC = utility.createImageSecret("$PREVIEW_NAMESPACE")
      }

      steps {
        script {
          utility.logMessage('****************** Git Pull Started ****************')
          utility.checkDeployment()
        }        
        // ensure we're not on a detached head
        sendNotifications 'STARTED'
        sh "git checkout $BRANCH_NAME"
        sh "git config --global credential.helper store"
        sh "git tag -l"
        sh "echo $BRANCH_NAME-v\$(jx-release-version)-b$BUILD_NUMBER > VERSION"
      }
    }
```

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/status-code-128/qaq-p/1998479

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates for your comment, however I believe that the post is not related to my issue, as the repo size is relatively small and does not exceed 100 MB. regarding the Jenkins bug for the plugin update, it is not the case as we did not perform any update on the plugins. Also I can confirm that this issue started to happen directly after changing the password from account password to app password, I.e. that was the only change that was done before this issue started to happen.

Comment: The issue is clearly in neither Git itself nor in Bitbucket, but rather in Jenkins. (Otherwise it would be consistent.) Little if any of your pipeline above is being used at the time the clone fails: note the lack of the "Git Pull Started" message in the output. So what seems to be happening is that Jenkins is using the wrong credentials to clone, but only in some cases; in other cases, Jenkins is using the right credentials to clone. Investigate where Jenkins gets its credentials.

Comment: @torek thanks for your feedback, I got to this conclusion also after seeing that the failure is happening before the pipeline actually starts to run. My problem here, is that I am not able to pin point where this is happening. we have even tried updating all our pipelines to use a totally new username and password created in Jenkins to avoid this issue, but it is still happening. I have also searched my code to check where the credentials are being used and which one is actually being used, and updated all of them with the new credentials.